# Is it possible to observe MockMvc tests with Fiddler?

Tags: java, spring, fiddler, spring-test-mvc, mockmvc

I am testing my web-app with

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApp.class)
//@WebAppConfiguration
@WebIntegrationTest
public class MyTest {

   private MockMvc mockMvc;

   @Autowired
   private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

}

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
   this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
       .apply(springSecurity())
       .build();
}

@Test
public void someTest() throws Exception {
 result = mockMvc.perform(get("/user/"));

      result
         .andExpect(status().isOk())
         .andExpect(content().contentType(contentType))
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to observe how tests run with Filler? Or it sends without network? Is it possible to force `MockMvc` to use network?

Currently I see nothing in Fiddler.

Setting of

```
  System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
  System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "8888");
```

didn't help.